# Submit button not working when the page is refreshed -javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The code is given below:

```
    <button type="button" class = "butt1" id ="submit" name ="submit" onclick="myAns(); this.disabled = true;"> Answer </button>

<script>
        function myAns(){
        for(var t=0; t <=count-1; t++) { 
        var table = document.getElementById("tableid");
        var row = table.insertRow(t);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell1.innerHTML =array[t];

            }
    }
</script>
```

1. I am trying to make sure submit button works only once when clicked.
2. The given code above works fine with chrome, if the page is refreshed, you can click once more.
3. In firefox, the given code also works once if the page is not refreshed.
4. In firefox, if the page is refreshed,you cannot click again.
   Can anyone provide the solution or show a way to do so?
5. Basically, I want to make sure the submit button is clickable only once at each refresh. The code is fine for Chrome but I need a solution at FireFox.

Comment: There is no code though, m8. Also a page-regresh, unless you are using cookies (or some other form of data storage) is gonna reset the variables so you will always be able to re-click it again.

Comment: You can have better control if you can store the click at server side. Else on client side all you can do is rely on browser's storage i.e. cookies or HTML5 storage i.e `localStorage`

Comment: @SidBrown press the code brackets to make code appear in your question

Comment: try adding a counter in your javascript function to only allow one answer. You haven't shown your js function. (It would help.) Counters are an easy way of keeping track of things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
cell1.innerHTML =array[t];
```

change to this:

```
cell1.innerHTML = t;
```

```html
<table id="tableid">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button id="submit" onclick="a(event)">Click Me!</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('submit').removeAttribute('disabled');
        function a(e)
        {
            for (var t = 0; t <= 5 - 1; t++)
            {
                var table = document.getElementById("tableid");
                var row = table.insertRow(t);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                cell1.innerHTML = t;

            }
  e.target.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: But i tested in fire fox. instead of 'count' put a number for example 5.            for (var t = 0; t <= 5 - 1; t++). Do you have a table named tableid?

Comment: I have the table named tableid. My problem is only with FireFox not Chrome. So, i think my logic is fine. I tried the above code, the problem is that you can click the button again and again without refreshing. It should be clickable only once, when the page refreshed.

Comment: I edited my code. Now the button will be disabled after on click. And as i said my browser is firefox so.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work too. Yes, the button only clicks once but my problem is bigger than that. When the button is clicked and then page is refreshed, it is no more clickable. It should be clickable, but only once at each refresh,...i hope you understand what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Now it is what you want. When page loads button is ready to click, then after click it will be disabled.